# Is darts a solitaire game?

Tags: darts

Looking through the rules of darts, it looks like a solitaire game to me - here meaning that it doesn't matter who you're playing against, there's always a well-defined set of actions you're trying to take. No matter what the current score is or who the opponent is, there is a minimum number of throws you need to finish, and that's what you should be going for. This is in contrast to a game like tennis, where you need to react to what your opponent does.

However, there are some statements by top darts players that make this impression seem incorrect, e.g. in the Wikipedia article on the [split in darts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_in_darts):

> In 2006, in what was described as a "massive coup", Raymond van Barneveld moved to the PDC. Van Barneveld said he was switching for the challenge and to "compete against the best players in the world, including the best, Phil Taylor."

If darts is a solitaire game, then it's irrelevant if you're competing against the best players in the world. Another example is that the championships are decided in 1-on-1 matches. If darts is a solitaire game, then one could just have everyone throw say 50 legs, and the person with the best average wins.

Questions:

- Is darts a solitaire game?
- If no, where does the interaction with the opponent come from? (Other than things like trashtalking one another on stage)

Comment: If you look at darts as a turn-based racing game then the interaction between players becomes more important. The winner is the first person to reach 501 and have the last dart a double, not who scored the greater average.

Comment: @TheFootsie but then you could measure who reached 501 in the fewest number of darts or something, instead of the average, and it would be just as good (?)

Comment: but that is how its decided. Whoever reaches 501 first with a double as the last dart wins the leg. The average as used by TV is like shots on target in soccer, it gives you an idea of whats going on but it isnt the score.

Answer (score 1):

The reality of the situation is (as very commonly) that "challenge the best in the world" is/was just code for "get more money"; the PDC always paid more than the BDO (the competing side in the split), but players didn't like to appear to be doing it *just* for the money.

Comment: I added another example, which doesn't look like it's explained by "more money".

Comment: @Allure you're right that darts is _mostly_ a solitaire game, but average certainly isn't everything see e.g. Williams vs (coincidentally!) van Barneveld at the most recent PDC championship, where van Barneveld won 4-1 despite having a significantly lower average (89.16 vs 91.71). I suspect the real reason though is that just watching players throw for average would be very boring television.